# Maintain integrity of element using Triggers or FK

Tags: sql-server

I'm nearly there with this design thanks to help previously from some Stackers.

[image]

The premise is simple in the real world.

- A Product has a ProductType which in turn has a ProductTypeGroup;
- A Product has Attributes which in turn has an AttributeGroup.

The bridging tables ensure that AttributeGroups can be assigned to specific ProductGroups and Attributes can be assigned to specific ProductTypes. There is also integrity between the 2 bridging tables.

However, I'm still allowed to add orphaned Attributes (ones that don't exist in the bridging tables) to be assigned as ProductAttributes. This needs to be pinned down so that the Attribute must relate correctly to the ProductType set on the Product itself, and any orphaned or unmatched attributes, should be constrained.

Once again I turn to the 'Trigger' (my solution for anything I can't make work), but given we have so many relationships already established, it may be also be possible to achieve the result using what we've got, or in a modified form.

As I'm not a seasoned SQL pro, nor even a seasoned newbie, I'm finding it difficult to see a workable pattern, so would appreciate a pair of expert eyes.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I'm now aware that orphaned Attributes can be constrained with a key between ProductTypes_Attributes_ProductAttributes, but doesn't resolved the non matching Attributes scenario.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue here. One comment I would make is to NOT use ID as the column name for anything ever. It is ambiguous and forces you to change column names for the same data property in various tables. Go ahead and name it ProductID in the Product table. It really is the ProductID at all times. The same is true of all your tables.

Comment: Thanks Sean - I tend to use ID in the principle table purely because of the way it pans out in the ORM (Product.ID rather than Product.ProductID). In all other tables I refer to ProductID. I see how this could become confusing - its just another one of those inexperienced decisions.

Comment: And the issue is theat ProductAttributes need to constrain the AttributeID to one that is permitted for the ProductType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty open ended question and if I had all day I'd quite enjoy re-modelling from scratch (not saying I'd necessarily come up with a different approach, but I'd enjoy the exercise). But I don't have all day, so I *think* this will give you what you want.

1. Remove the FK from ProductAttributes to Attributes (this FK is the source of your current issue)
2. Remove the FK
   from ProductAttributes to Product
3. Add a ProductTypeID column to
   ProductAttributes
4. Create an alternative key in
   ProductTypes_Attributes on (ProductTypeID, AttributeID)
5. Create an
   alternative key in Product on (ID, ProductTypeID) (or you could add ProductTypeID to the primary key)
6. Create an FK from
   ProductAttributes to Product on (ProductID, ProductTypeID)
7. Create an
   FK from ProductAttributes to ProductTypes_Attributeson
   (ProductTypeID, AttributeID)

I haven't coded this up to test, but it seems about right in my head. Whether it helps you or not might depend on whether your ORM likes it.

Comment: Worked this through and it works - the only compromise as far as the Orm is concerned is the extra column in the table. Of course these can be removed manually, but to be honest its less hassle just to leave it there. Thanks Rhys.